# How to call image src attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have done some code in jquery but where i commented in this bellow code i need to call image src instead of .text can any one help for my question.

```
$(".open").live('click', function () {
                $("#navMenu").animate({
                    width: "85px"
                }, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 500,
                    complete: function () {
                        //$(".open").text("CLOSE");
                        var $this = $(".open");
                        $this.removeClass();
                        $this.addClass("close");
                    }
                });
            });

            $(".close ").live('click', function () {
                $("#navMenu ").animate({
                    width: "52px"
                }, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 500,
                    complete: function () {
                        //$(".close").text("OPEN");
                        var $this = $(".close");
                        $this.removeClass();
                        $this.addClass("open");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you the src :

```
var source = $("#myImage").attr("src");
```

Comment: this below format is not working $(".open").attr("src","images/open_arrow.png");

Comment: I will need more context to determine what is going wrong, it might be a good idea to make a new question for this so you can include all the details.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `.close` is the collection of your images, you can get the src attribute value(s) simply by using:

```
var src = $('.close').attr('src');
```

If you want to alter the src attribute:

```
$('.close').attr('src', 'my new value');
```

[jQuery .attr() API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to set/change the src attr,
to so you can do something like

```
 $('#image').atrr('src', newSrc);
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

helmus answer is correct for getting the image src value,

If you want to set the src value, you should do like this

```
$("#myImage").attr("src","http://newimage.com/new.jpg");
```